# different page size and frame size for processes

Tags: memory-management, process, operating-system, paging

Can  there be different page size and frame size for different processes ? for eg. if process p1 has divided into 5 pages of 4MB  and process p2 has divided into 4 pages of 3Mb so what would be the frame size in this case will it be 4MB for p1 and 3 Mb for p2?

expecting the frame size for p1 and p2 and how does the frames are allocated

Comment: Why would any hardware/OS designer want to try to support this?  I find it difficult to understand how overall virtual memory could be managed..

Answer (score 0):

The available page sizes are decided by the hardware. Absolutely all hardware requires page sizes to be powers of 2: so a page size of 3MB is never used.

On the matter of your question: not only different processes can have different page sizes, but even the same process can use several page sizes.

In architectures with hardware-driven paging (most architectures, including x86, ARM, RISC-V, etc) page sizes are usually determined by the boundaries between levels of page tables. On x86_64, for example, the available page sizes are 4kB, 2MB and 1GB. Each is 512 times bigger than the previous one - because page tables are 512 entries in size.

Architectures with software-driven paging can have more options. For example, MIPS allows all page sizes between 4kB and 256MB, in multiples of 4. OS can decide, which ones it will support - it is ultimately responsible for storing the page tables in RAM.